# char* and cin in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I would like to input a string of indefinite length to a char * variable using cin;

I can do this:

```
char * tmp = "My string";
cout << tmp << endl;
system("pause");
```

It works perfectly.

But I fail to do this:

```
 char * tmp
 cin >> tmp;
```

Could you give me a hing what's wrong"

Comment: try `std::string str; cin >> str;`

Comment: You need to learn about memory allocation. Currently, with `char * tmp`, all you do is declare a pointer to a memory location, but you don't actually allocate memory to hold the string.

Comment: BTW: `std::cin >> some_string` will only get the first word.  Sure, it's of "indefinite length"...technically... :)  If you want more than the first word, you'll need to use something different.

Comment: If I got one cent every time this question is asked, I could by Apple. Twice.

Comment: Never use `cin >> x;` where `x` is a `char*` or a `char` array, without first setting the width on `cin`, using either the `width` member function, or the `setw` i/o manipulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you havn't created an object for the `char*` to point to.

```
char* tmp = new char[MAX_LENGTH];
```

should make it work better (you have to define MAX_LENGTH).
Another way to do this is:

```
std::string strtmp;
cin >> strtmp;
const char* tmp = strtmp.c_str();
```

This method would mean that you need not use `new`.

Comment: `c_str` is `const char*` though

Comment: So true, updated that. One would have to copy the string to another variable before changing it.

Comment: `delete tmp` would break. You're not the owner of that `char*`, `strtmp` is and will delete it when it gets destroyed. Which means your code is pretty dangerous - you need to keep `strtmp` alive as long as `tmp` is in use.

Comment: Unless you copy the c_string into a new char* variable. Removed the thing about delete though - good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of issues:

```
char * tmp
cin >> tmp;
```

tmp is not allocated (it is currently random).

`operator>>` (when used with char* or string) reads a single (white space separated) word.

Issue 1:

If you use `char*` and allocate a buffer then you may not allocate enough space. The read may read more characters than is available in the buffer. A better idea is to use std::string (from this you can get a C-String).

Issue 2:

There is no way to read indefinite string. But you can read a line at a time using `std::getline`.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

char* str = line.data();
```