# Float variable in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, and encountering these problems in a simple program, so please help me out.

This is the code

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
int main()
{   float pie;
    pie = (22/7);
    cout<<"The Value of Pi(22/7) is "<< pie<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
The Value of Pi(22/7) is 3
```

Why is the value of Pi not in decimal?

Comment: [This.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319690/c-char-and-cin#comment21629645_15319690)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're doing **integer division**.

**What you want is really float division:**

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
int main()
{   
    float pie;
    pie = float(22)/7;//        22/(float(7)) is also equivalent

    cout<<"The Value of Pi(22/7) is "<< pie<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, this type conversion: `float(variable)` or `float(value)` isn't type safe.

You could have gotten the value you wanted by ensuring that the values you were computing were floating point to begin with as follows:

```
22.0/7
```

OR

```
22/7.0
```

OR

```
22.0/7.0
```

But, that's generally a hassle and will involve that you keep track of all the types you're working with. Thus, the **final and best method involves using static_cast**:

```
static_cast<float>(22)/7
```

OR

```
22/static_cast<float>(7)
```

As for why you **should** use static_cast - see this:

[Why use static_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)

Answer (score 0):

```
pie = (22/7);
```

Here the division is integer division, because both operands are `int`.

What you intend to do is floating-point division:

```
pie = (22.0/7);
```

Here `22.0` is `double`, so the division becomes floating-point division (even though `7` is still `int`).

The rule is that IF both operands are integral type (such as `int`, `long`, `char` etc), then it is integer division, ELSE it is floating-point division (i.e when even if a single operand is `float` or `double`).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
      pi = 22/7.0
```

If u give the two operands to the / operator as integer then the division performed will be integer division and a float will not be the result.